# Search bar appearing when swiping down in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, search

I'm building an Android app using Kotlin, I wanted to implement a search there but I want it somehow hidden (just like the search bar is in every iPhone), which will only show up if you swipe down. Can this actually be implemented in an android app?

Comment: It's programming, you can implement any UI concept you can dream up. I think you could do this by creating a full screen layout that has it's contents shifted up by the height you want to drag it down and starts invisible. Have it handle touch without intercepting touch, to pull its contents down to their natural 0 Y offset and enable the controls when in this state. But this topic is too detailed for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try the following code:**

`MainActivity.kt` file:

```
package com.realtomjoney.searchbar_app

import android.animation.Animator
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat
import com.realtomjoney.searchbar_app.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlin.math.abs

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private  lateinit var detector: GestureDetectorCompat

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setBindings()

        detector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, PrimaryGestureListener())
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return if (detector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            true
        } else {
            super.onTouchEvent(event)
        }
    }

    inner class PrimaryGestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        private val swipeThreshold = 100
        private val swipeVelocityThreshold = 100

        override fun onFling(
            downEvent: MotionEvent?,
            moveEvent: MotionEvent?,
            velocityX: Float,
            velocityY: Float
        ): Boolean {
            val diffX = moveEvent?.x?.minus(downEvent!!.x) ?: 0.0F
            val diffY = moveEvent?.y?.minus(downEvent!!.y) ?: 0.0F

            if (abs(diffX) <= abs(diffY) &&
                abs(diffY) > swipeThreshold && abs(velocityY) > swipeVelocityThreshold ) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    this@MainActivity.binding.activityMainSearchViewTextInputLayout.alpha = 0f
                    this@MainActivity.binding.activityMainSearchViewTextInputLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    this@MainActivity.binding.activityMainSearchViewTextInputLayout
                        .animate()
                        .alpha(1f).setDuration(800)
                        .setListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                                this@MainActivity.binding.activityMainSearchViewTextInputLayout.visibility =
                                    View.VISIBLE
                            }
                        })
                } else {
                    this@MainActivity.binding.activityMainSearchViewTextInputLayout
                        .animate()
                        .alpha(0f).setDuration(200)
                        .setListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                                this@MainActivity.binding.activityMainSearchViewTextInputLayout.visibility =
                                    View.GONE
                            }
                        })
                }
            }

            return super.onFling(downEvent, moveEvent, velocityX, velocityY)
        }
    }

    private fun setBindings() {
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/activityMain_searchViewTextInputLayout"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Feel free to adjust  `swipeThreshold` `swipeVelocityThreshold` to your liking. The animations aren't the best, so I'd also recommend you change them.

**GIF:**

[image]

---

**Video that helped me detect swipe gestures:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1aydFEOEA0

Comment: Okay, I will try this and will let you know, I appreciate it

Comment: @FrensisXh any updates?

Comment: Yes, It worked.